# testcomplete doesnt support developer express 12.2.7?

Tags: vbscript, devexpress, testcomplete

I am working on  a application which includes a developer express Datagrid version 12.2.7 . i have checked the supported list of controls from here :

visit http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55638/

according to which the version which i have is technically not supported ? does that mean i cannot use testcomplete for that grid ? or do i have to upgrade the version base in my application too?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this means that SmartBear did not test this functionality with this specific version of the controls. Most probably, TestComplete should work without any problems with it.

Comment: i recieved a mail from them saying it doesnt support , because i was not able to get the    gridobj.MainView.ViewInfo.Cards.CardFieldInfoBy(RowHandle, Column).Bounds  specifically was not able to get the Cards property

Comment: The properties you list are native properties. Advanced support for a control means extra high-level actions and not access to the native properties that is provided by the Open Applications feature. So, I think that this is not related to the DX controls support feature of TestComplete.